# Decomissioning an SVN server, keeping SVN storage files. How to access later?

Tags: svn

We have an SVN server that we'd like to decomission. All the SVN related files on the server is  stored  on a remote storage.

Looking directly at the each svn repository folder on the remote storage, the folder format looks like this:

[Each SVN repository folder format on remote storage (example 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73T00.png)

[Each SVN repository folder format on remote storage (example 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJQ40.png)

We will be keeping the files on remote storage as it is. I would like to avoid doing svnadmin dump for each of the repository as the total svn repository size is pretty large (3.3TB).

My question, once the SVN server has been decomissioned and keeping the SVN files system storage as it is, is it possible to attach a new SVN server to the existing storage so that we can access the files again if needed? Or are there another way to access the files without attaching an SVN server.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to archive and then access the repository later. You might want to look into the recommended backup and migration procedure for your SVN server.

For example: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin

Comment: «I would like to avoid doing svnadmin dump for each of the repository as the total svn repository size is pretty large (3.3TB).» said the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In short: "yes", but you should record two things about this server:

1. the exact H/W+OS platform (that is, 32 vs 64 bits, and version of the OS);
2. the exact version of the Subversion server.

If it's a non-Windows system — that is, an OS with a real package manager, — do record the versions of all the packages the Subversion server's package depends on.

The explanation is as follows:

- **The internal storage backend files are not defined to be portable,** and in fact, over the course of the Subversion development they did change, new were added, old were phased out etc.
- Still, with a particular combo of H/W+OS and the version of the Subversion server, it should be possible to access these backend storage files. The repository metadata does record which type (and which version) of the format the actual storage is.

I'd also note that it may be just okay to keep the OS+server installed on the server (or backed up somewhere along with the repository data) as the size of this "dead data" will be miniscule compared to the size of the data of the repositories, and in the case you'll later need to access them, it will be just a matter of booting that OS (may be after restoring it from a backup).